# ¿Como puedo imprimir un cartel simil alerta JavaScript dentro de mi código php?

Tags: php

Necesito imprimir un cartel que le avise al usuario que una imagen ha sido borrada con exito.

```
<?php
include('conexion.php');

if(isset($_REQUEST['id']) && !empty($_REQUEST['id'])){

    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];

    if ($resultado = mysqli_query($link, "DELETE from Productos where id = ".$id))
        {
            printf('<script language="javascript">alert("'."Imagen borrada con exito".'");</script>');
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
        else
        {
            print "Fallo la consulta: ". mysqli_error($link);
            die;
        }

        echo json_encode($arr);
        mysqli_close($link);
}

?>
```

Intenté con echo, con print, con printf, pero no hay forma de que salga el cartel. ¿Estoy haciendo algo mal?

El direccionamiento al index me lo hace bien, pero el cartel no me lo imprime :/

Comment: Como bien indica @DiegoArce en su respuesta, el problema era la redirección, que la estabas haciendo desde el servidor. Al redirigir desde el cliente, problema resuelto. Y usa `echo`, es mucho más eficaz que `printf` en este caso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

espero ayudarte, yo hago que me salgan los alert de esta forma y a la vez, redirecciono al index en el script.

```
echo "<script>
              alert('Imagen borrada con éxito');
              window.location= 'index.php'
      </script>";
```

Comment: Excelente, así me funciona bien, que es todo lo que necesito para ESTE proyecto ! Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Lo que quieres conseguir, se suele hacer por medio de **modales** que no es otra cosa que una "ventana" de HTML que se sobrepone a la pantalla.

**EJEMPLO**

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

La manera en la que tratas de hacerlo no es correcta:

**PHP**

```
printf('<script language="javascript">alert("'."Imagen borrada con exito".'");</script>');
header("Location: index.php");
```

**PHP** es un lenguaje del lado del servidor, su ejecución está por delante de los que se ejecutan del lado del cliente. Tu **printf** está escribiendo correctamente el código, lo que pasa es que la línea de ejecución no va a esperar a que el navegador lo interprete y te muestre el **alert**, si no que va a continuar interpretando el código, llegando a la redirección y saliéndose sin que se llegue a ejecutar nada de **Javascript**

Comment: Los modales son una especie en extinción. Yo no los recomendaría. Eso impresionaba en los 90, con la fiebre de Windows. Pero hoy no.

Comment: Se podría debatir largo y tendido sobre eso. Pero lo que es hoy por hoy, son una realidad que se ve en casi todas las páginas o aplicaciones Web. Bootstrap 4.0 me daría la razón.

Comment: Hoy por hoy para lo único que sirve un modal es para sacarte en pantalla la por lo demás **molesta** ventana de suscripción que presentan algunos sitios cuando llevas X segundos navegando en ellos o cuando te desplazas un poco hacia abajo. Para otras cosas, con la llegada por ejemplo de Ajax, que te permite desde una misma pantalla enviar/recibir datos entre cliente/servidor. Con HTML5 que te permite embeber todo tipo de contenidos en la misma pantalla, etc., no le veo ninguna utilidad a los modales. Son horribles y desagradables desde el punto de vista de la experiencia de usuario.

Comment: Y te doy la razón, pero se usan en todos lados, los frameworks más usados las utilizan, los CMSs más usados más de lo mismo. Dejando a un lado el uso que se les de, más o menos intrusivo, es algo que a día de hoy se sigue usando, incluso con AJAX caminando entre nosotros unos cuantos años ya.

Comment: Yo uso WP hace ya varios años y nunca he visto un modal. Ellos usan barras de estado en la parte superior para emitir informaciones. No son intrusivas (como los modales) y son además elegantes. En Ajax tampoco he tenido nunca necesidad de usarlos para nada. Es más, en este mismo caso planteado, sería mucho más elegante, en vez de un alert de Javascript, presentar una barra informativa en la parte superior, la cual puedes presentar/ocultar con una línea de código CSS. Se pueden además poner efectos mientras la página hace la redirección... Mejora la UX, todo lo contrario del *intrusivo* modal.

Comment: Wordpress hace uso de los llamados thickbox, que son primos hermanos de las ventanas modales. Los incorpora de manera nativa (a través de una librería de Jquery) y los emplea en su propia interface, sobre todo en el visor de themes, cuando subes archivos e imágenes al servidor, en la galería de imágenes, editor de imágenes... Las técnicas que tú propones son también muy válidas y coincido en que son menos intrusivas, pero las modales a día de hoy siguen siendo una alternativa válida, y que se emplea en infinidad de sitios de lo más actuales.